# Wrong linespacing in section title

Tags: sectioning, line-spacing

I have a problem with spacing in section title where section number is bigger than the title. The first and second line are separated by  a quite big space. Space after second line is normal. I am not able get good enough result

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[RO]{\scriptsize{Indikátory udržitelnosti rozvoje hl. m. Prahy  }\hspace*{4pt}\vheadline \hspace*{0.72in} \vheadline\hspace*{13pt}\linepagesep\normalsize \thepage }
  \fancyfoot[RO]{\textbf{\emph{UAP }}\hskip \vfootline\hskip\linepagesep\textbf{\emph{2016}}}
  \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
  \newskip\linepagesep \linepagesep 5pt\relax
  \def\vfootline{%ñ
    \begingroup\rule[-990pt]{1pt}{1000pt}\endgroup}
  \def\vheadline{%
    \begingroup\rule[-5pt]{0.5pt}{35pt}\endgroup}


\titleformat{\section}{\vspace*{6pt}\bfseries\fontsize{36}{36}\selectfont\bfseries}{\thesection.}{55 pt}{\Large\bfseries\MakeUppercase}{}
%\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{50ex plus 2ex}{10pt}
\fancyheadoffset[RO]{0.20in}
\fancyfootoffset[RO]{0.20in}
\usepackage[paperheight=11.14in,paperwidth=7.71in,left=0.55in,right=0.7in,top=0.36in,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\definecolor{gray}{RGB}{165,165,165}

\definecolor{darkgray}{RGB}{125,125,125}
\setmainfont[
Path = C:/Windows/Fonts/,
BoldFont = UnitPro-Medi.otf,
ItalicFont = UnitPro-Ita.otf,
BoldItalicFont  = UnitPro-Bold.otf]{UnitPro-Light.otf} % bold italic pouzit jako bold verzi

\pagestyle{fancy}

\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.15,
   x axis line style={semithick,gray},
   y axis line style= { draw opacity=0 },
   every axis label/.append style ={darkgray},
   every tick label/.append style={darkgray},
   grid style = { semithick,gray}
 }

\begin{document}
\newpage

\linespread{1}
\section {Hrubý domácí produkt na obyvatele v paritě kupní síly (EU = 100) zde je dalsi text, ktery se musi zobrazovat  s malou mezerou}
\linespread{1.25}
\vskip
\footnotesize{KATEGORIE INDIKÁTORU : }\small\textbf{hlavní}
\newline
\footnotesize{PILÍŘE HOSPODÁŘSKÉHO ROZVOJE (H = hospodářský(ekonomický) / S = sociální / E = environmentální) : }\small\textbf{E}
\newline
\footnotesize{VZTAHUJE SE KE KAPITOLE : }\small\textbf{432 hospodářský podmínka}
\newline
\footnotesize{VZTAHUJE SE K JEVU : }\small\textbf{B037/02}
\newline
\footnotesize{ZDORJ DAT : }\small\textbf{Eurostat, 2016}
\newline
\newline
\footnotesize{POPIS INDIKÁTORU : }\footnotesize\textit{Eurostat, 2016 Eurostat, 2016 Eurostat, 2016 Eurostat, 2016 Eurostat, 2016 Eurostat, 2016 Eurostat, 2016 Eurostat, 2016 Eurostat, 2016 Eurostat, 2016 Eurostat, 2016 Eurostat, 2016 Eurostat, 2016}
\newline
\newline
\newline
\vspace{10pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=0.95\textwidth,
height=0.3\textheight,
scale only axis,
xmin=1994.5,
xmax=2016.5,
xtick={1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016},
xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,font=\tiny},
xtick align=outside,
ymin=0,
ymax=4,
ytick={1, 2, 3, 3},
ytick align =center,
ylabel={[jednotka]},
yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/precision=3,font=\tiny},
ytick style ={draw=none},
ymajorgrids,
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left
]
\addplot [color=black,mark = *,mark size=1,solid,line width=0.5pt,forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{
1998    1.3  \\
1999    1.5  \\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\newline
\newline
\footnotesize{ŽÁDOUCÍ TREND : }\small\textbf{růst}
\newline
\newline
\footnotesize{DATA [jednotka]: }\\
\begin{tabular}{cS[math-rm=\mathbf,table-format=3.2]@{\hspace{5em}}cS[math-rm=\mathbf,table-format=3.2]@{\hspace{5em}}cS[math-rm=\mathbf,table-format=3.2]}
    -    &   & 2000 &  8 & 2010 & 10 \\
    -    &   & 2001 &  8 & 2011 & 10 \\
    -    &   & 2002 &  8 & 2012 & 10 \\
    -    &   & 2003 &  8 & 2013 & 10 \\
    -    &   & 2004 &  8 & 2014 & 10 \\
    1995 & 5 & 2005 &  8 & 2015 & 10 \\
    1996 & 6 & 2006 &  9 & 2016 & 12 \\
    1997 & 7 & 2007 & 10 & & \\
    1998 & 7 & 2008 & 10 & & \\
    1999 & 7 & 2009 & 10 & & \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Result is like this:

[image]

Thanks for any idea.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: welcome.  i can't test this because i don't have the font, but i think the problem may be related to the depth of the font used for the large numeral (even though it has no descender).  try applying `\smash[b]{...}` to that element and see if the situation improves.

Comment: i'm not sure where to put the command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
\titleformat{\section}{\vspace*{6pt}\bfseries\fontsize{36}{36}\selectfont\bfseries}{\thesection.}{55 pt}{\Large\bfseries\MakeUppercase}{}
```

to this:

```
\titleformat{\section}{\vspace*{6pt}\fontsize{36}{\the\baselineskip}\selectfont\bfseries}{\thesection.}{55pt}{\Large\bfseries\MakeUppercase}{}
```